# Bitcoin charts for websites

Tags: charts, website-integration

Does anyone know of any good paid or open source software solutions for displaying Bitcoin charts on a customer facing website?

There are three main types of charts we want to offer at this stage:

1. [MtGox Live](http://mtgoxlive.com/orders) style (not sure what this type of chart is called but would love to know if someone does?)
2. Candlestick Charts like at http://bitcoincharts.com/charts
3. Basic line graphs like at http://blockchain.info/charts

I have to date found the following:

- Google charts https://developers.google.com/chart/ These unfortunately don't really cut it.
- StatsMix http://www.statsmix.com/ The pricing a little higher than I wanted to pay for this solution.

As for where to get the data feeds I am okey with this. It's only the web facing charts that I need to find a solution toif anyone has come across before?

Comment: If you're wanting charting software, then you might like to try asking on stackoverflow (or searching, as it's probably already been asked). You're aware of bitcoincharts.com I presume?

Comment: Will close this as the question is just about finding a charting library and not about getting Bitcoin data to display. Please follow Highly Irregular's advice and ask a question on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.highcharts.com is pretty good (Blockchain.info uses it). Charts can be rendered both client and server side which is useful for png previews.